# How can I differentiate the same method name of two protocols in a class implementation?

Tags: objective-c, oop, ios5, protocols

I have two protocols

```
@protocol P1

-(void) printP1;

-(void) printCommon;

@end


@protocol P2

-(void) printP2;

-(void) printCommon;
@end
```

Now, I am implementing these two protocols in one class

```
@interface TestProtocolImplementation : NSObject <P1,P2>
{

}

@end
```

How can i write method implementation for "printCommon". When i try to do implementation i have compile time error.

Is there any possibility to write method implementation for "printCommon".

Comment: Can you post your error and your implementation?

Comment: #pragma mark -
#pragma mark P1 protocol methods
-(void)printP1
{
 NSLog(@"print p1");
}

-(void) printCommon
{
 NSLog(@"Print P1");
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark P2 protocol methods
-(void)printP2
{
 NSLog(@"print p2");
}


-(void) printCommon 
{
 NSLog(@"Print P2"); 
}

Error: redefinition of '-[TestObjectLifeCycle printCommon]'

It is working good when i remove any one of "printCommon" method implementation.

Answer (score 14):

The common solution is to separate the common protocol and make the derived protocols implement the common protocol, like so:

```
@protocol PrintCommon

-(void) printCommon;

@end

@protocol P1 < PrintCommon > // << a protocol which declares adoption to a protocol

-(void) printP1;

// -(void) printCommon; << available via PrintCommon

@end


@protocol P2 < PrintCommon >

-(void) printP2;

@end
```

Now types which adopt `P1` and `P2` must also adopt `PrintCommon`'s methods in order to fulfill adoption, and you may safely pass an `NSObject<P1>*` through `NSObject<PrintCommon>*` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

for me the following code did worked:

```
@protocol P1    

- (void) method1;

@end

@protocol P2

- (void) method1;
- (void) method2;

@end

@interface C1 : NSObject<P1, P2>

@end

@implementation C1

- (void) method1
{
    NSLog(@"method1");
}

- (void) method2
{
    NSLog(@"method2");
}

@end
```

Compiler user: Apple LLVM 3.0
But if you're designing a solution like this, try to avoid such situations.