# what should do for same method in multiple protocols? (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, protocols

Say I have protocols ProA and ProB. They both have a method -(void) testingMethod;

And I have another class ClassAB which implementes both of these protocols. What should I do for the testingMethod?

I know we can implement only one testingMethod. But what should I do if I want to have two testingMethods in class ClassAB, for ProA and Prob respectively?

Comment: Why do you need to have a method with the same name in both protocols?

Comment: We can assume the protocols were not defined by me, for example, AViewDelegate and BViewDelagate, both have method viewDidLoaded

Comment: [Properly named delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001803-BCIDAIJE) identify the class doing the delegation, since they're supposed to pass a reference to the sender. So this is very unlikely to happen in practice. Especially with Apple's own APIs.

Comment: @yuji even though very unlikely but this can happen when you are using two open source projects and both having the same method name.. ?

Comment: I agree that it's *possible*. I just wanted to emphasize that if people use the right conventions with the method signatures and names of their delegate methods, it's **very** unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

There's also the case where you're simply using two libraries that define protocols with methods that have the same name, as a coincidence, so you can't modify them.
 In that case you would need to create two classes, one implementing each protocol, let's say `ClassA` for `ProA` and `ClassB` for `ProB`, and then pass your instance of `ClassAB` to each of them.
 When `ClassA` receives a call from `testingMethod` you make it call ClassAB's method, for example `classAB testingMethodA`. 
If it's not clear tell me and I write the implement.

Comment: Good answer that understands the problem and gives a constructive answer. 

Answer (score 2):

you should separate the common protocol method in a different protocol and create two new protocols implementing the earlier protocol.. see it is very well explained here.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992461/919545

Answer (score 1):

Just rename method in first protocol to testingMethod1 and method in second protocol to testingMethod2